# How to fix server error while pushing an image to the Docker hub?

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-registry

I've built an image from a Dockerfile, committed it and am now trying to push it to the Hub. The command I run:

```
sudo docker push lisahelm/mongo:v2
```

What prints out:

```
The push refers to a repository [lisahelm/mongo] (len: 1)  
7b6d0719b415: Image already exists  
975e0be2d43f: Image already exists  
ee08822aa3f9: Image already exists  
96f2191238d5: Image already exists  
07f8e8c5e660: Image already exists  
37bea4ee0c81: Image already exists    
a82efea989f9: Image already exists  
e9e06b06e14c: Image already exists  
FATA[0015] Error pushing to registry: Server error: 400 trying to push lisahelm/mongo:v2 manifest
```

Info I've seen people ask for in other questions:

```
Docker version 1.6.0, build 4749651/1.6.0
Containers: 4  
Images: 22  
Storage Driver: devicemapper   
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-263695-pool   
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB  
 Backing Filesystem: extfs  
 Data file: /dev/loop0  
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1   
 Data Space Used: 2.222 GB   
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB   
 Data Space Available: 4.88 GB   
 Metadata Space Used: 2.58 MB    
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB   
 Metadata Space Available: 2.145 GB   
 Udev Sync Supported: true   
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data   
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata   
 Library Version: 1.02.89-RHEL6 (2014-09-01)   
Execution Driver: native-0.2   
Kernel Version: 3.14.35-28.38.amzn1.x86_64   
Operating System: Amazon Linux AMI 2015.03  
CPUs: 1   
Total Memory: 1.957 GiB   
Name: ip-172-31-11-134   
ID: WVRW:3RM3:L4KL:YABF:JGSK:S6ML:U2CH:5Z5G:67CY:24BF:3DIE:E6TA   
Username: lisahelm   
Registry: [https://index.docker.io/v1/]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an Amazon AMI running RHEL.

The docker shipped by Amazon on these machines is defective.

The solution is to either switch to Ubuntu, or update docker manually on the instance.

You can read here for context and an answer from an AMZ dev: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13143#issuecomment-102522728

And here for another user coming up with an update solution: https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/538#issuecomment-104241554

Finally here for the Amazon support forum about this bug: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=622774